# Async work to sync to async has strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a legacy project with a lot of IoC and `HttpClient` calls. To improve performance, I'm trying try use TPL to parallelize the work. But the performance became worse.

In summary, we try parallelize a sync method which encapsulates an async method.
After refactoring, the performance is better, but I don't understands this behavior.

I made this minimal code example to reproduce the behavior in .NET 4.7 console project:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            var n = i;
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => WorkSync(n)));
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    private static void WorkSync(int i)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{i:000}\t{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}\tStartA");
        WorkAsync(i).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Debug.WriteLine($"{i:000}\t{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}\tFinishA");
    }

    private static async Task WorkAsync(int i)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{i:000}\t{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}\tStartB");
        await Task.Run(() => Work(i));
        Debug.WriteLine($"{i:000}\t{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}\tFinishB");
    }

    private static void Work(int i)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{i:000}\t{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}\tDo Something");
    }
}
```

Result :

```
004 11:30:10.629    StartA
000 11:30:10.627    StartA
002 11:30:10.627    StartA
001 11:30:10.627    StartA
003 11:30:10.627    StartA
005 11:30:10.628    StartA
006 11:30:10.628    StartA
007 11:30:10.628    StartA
008 11:30:10.633    StartA
002 11:30:10.692    StartB
001 11:30:10.692    StartB
000 11:30:10.692    StartB
003 11:30:10.692    StartB
005 11:30:10.692    StartB
004 11:30:10.692    StartB
006 11:30:10.695    StartB
007 11:30:10.699    StartB
008 11:30:10.703    StartB
009 11:30:11.632    StartA
009 11:30:11.633    StartB
010 11:30:12.616    StartA
010 11:30:12.617    StartB
011 11:30:13.612    StartA
011 11:30:13.613    StartB
012 11:30:14.612    StartA
012 11:30:14.613    StartB
013 11:30:15.612    StartA
013 11:30:15.613    StartB
014 11:30:16.611    StartA
014 11:30:16.612    StartB
002 11:30:17.612    Do Something
002 11:30:17.614    FinishB
002 11:30:17.615    FinishA
001 11:30:17.615    Do Something
001 11:30:17.657    FinishB
006 11:30:17.658    Do Something
005 11:30:17.636    Do Something
006 11:30:17.680    FinishB
005 11:30:17.701    FinishB
007 11:30:17.723    Do Something
001 11:30:17.658    FinishA
005 11:30:17.744    FinishA
004 11:30:17.744    Do Something
007 11:30:17.765    FinishB
004 11:30:17.808    FinishB
006 11:30:17.723    FinishA
007 11:30:17.830    FinishA
003 11:30:17.894    Do Something
013 11:30:17.786    Do Something
003 11:30:17.895    FinishB
013 11:30:17.917    FinishB
012 11:30:17.919    Do Something
008 11:30:17.830    Do Something
014 11:30:17.788    Do Something
004 11:30:17.851    FinishA
009 11:30:17.851    Do Something
013 11:30:17.922    FinishA
000 11:30:17.872    Do Something
003 11:30:17.918    FinishA
012 11:30:17.927    FinishB
010 11:30:17.922    Do Something
008 11:30:17.931    FinishB
014 11:30:17.933    FinishB
011 11:30:17.955    Do Something
008 11:30:18.046    FinishA
009 11:30:17.958    FinishB
009 11:30:18.111    FinishA
014 11:30:18.068    FinishA
000 11:30:17.980    FinishB
000 11:30:18.114    FinishA
010 11:30:18.024    FinishB
011 11:30:18.089    FinishB
012 11:30:18.003    FinishA
011 11:30:18.138    FinishA
010 11:30:18.116    FinishA
```

The `Work` method is executed only after all tasks are started in the Main.
I have checked this using the debugger, it isn't the debug display that blocks.

1) I don't understand this scheduling.
Can you explain why?

2) The 10 first tasks start very rapidly, but the last 5 tasks start very slowly.
Can you explain why?

Comment: Just a word of caution here: Output to the console does not _necessarily_ follow the order or timing of asynchronous code execution. You could end up chasing a red herring...

Comment: `Work` method is executed at the end because you spin up all the Tasks at the same time which will create multiple threads and those will be running in parallel. So nothing strange about out?

Comment: For testing those things you should actually use `async` methods instead of `Task.Run`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Could you add `{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}` to the result, so that we can see what is running slow and what is running fast?

Comment: @Martin just curious do you know if this is still true when using `Debug` instead of `Console`? I noticed that OP uses `Debug`.

Comment: @Matin, I put a breakpoint in the `Work` method. All `StartA` and `StartB` are displayed before the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: @JonasHøgh, I edited my question to explain my goal.

Comment: @Orwel you didn't really. The code you posted doens't make much sense - you execute an async operation only to block it and then you add back `Task.Run` to make it async again. Just remove the blocking code

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I edited the question to output time information.

Comment: @Orwel HttpClient is *already* asynchronous and thread-safe. HttpClient instances are meant to be reused, so perhaps the problem is using HttpClient in an inappropriate way. Or hitting a throttling limit on the server. Or hitting the 2 connections per domain limit, something that was enforced by older versions of HttpClient

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, You miss my edit. I corrected my real code, but I don't understands this behavior.

Comment: @Orwel on the contrary, I checked the edit history to see what the edit was about. The code is counterproductive and *blocks* already asynchronous operations. What does the *real* code do? How do you use `HttpClient` ?

Comment: @Orwel I make multiple concurrent calls with HttpClient too, to execute 1000+ requests to the same service, 5 at a time. I don't use Task.Run anywhere, or loops with tasks like this. To do so, in .NET Old I had to increase `servicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` above the default, 2. I also use classes like ActionBlock to make coding and controllable throttling a *LOT* easier

Comment: @Orwel there's no reason to increase the threadpool count if you don't *block* the threads to begin with

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank for information on HttpClient. I miss this.

Comment: Strange that you observe these delays, without any `Sleep` or `Delay` inside the tasks.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, See Matthew's answer.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. Interesting how you managed to block so many threads with so little code! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand this scheduling. Can you explain why?

You have a tight loop launching a load of tasks. They all start up, but each of them launches another thread. That thread is not being scheduled until after the launching thread calls `Debug.WriteLine($"{i:000}\tFinishB");`.

One reason why the `Work()` thread is being blocked is that `Debug.WriteLine()` acquires a lock - so if some other thread is currently writing to Debug the `Work()` thread will block. The moral of this is that `Debug.WriteLine()` can change the behaviour of multithreading, because it uses locks.

---

> The 10 first tasks start very speed, but the 5 last tasks start very slow. Can you explain why?

However, there is another more impactful reason that this is happening: The "min thread limit" for the threadpool.

The threadpool maintains a minimum number of threads ready waiting to run. You can see that value via the following code:

```
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out int workers, out int ports);
Console.WriteLine(workers);  // Prints 8 on my system.
```

Now the important thing to know here is that if more than the minimum number of threads are required, new ones will only be created after a delay of a few hundred milliseconds (not sure exactly how long, but it seems to be around one second).

So in addition to the blocking caused by locks in the `Debug.WriteLine()` implementation, the following is happening:

- A load of tasks are started, consuming more than the minimum threadpool size, so a delay is introduced between new tasks after the first few tasks are started.
- Because of this delay, by the time it comes to the `Work()` task being started, it's being delayed. This causes it to start much later than it would otherwise.

You can prove that this is happening by increasing the minimum number of threadpool threads at the start of your test code, and observing the difference in output.

To try this, add the following line of code before you launch any tasks:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
```

When I try that, all the tasks start more quickly, and some of the "Do Something" messages appear before all the other tasks are started (whereas previously those messages only appeared AFTER all the other tasks were started, as you noticed).

**NOTE** Microsoft [do not recommended to change the minimum number of threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool):

> You can use the ThreadPool.SetMinThreads method to increase the minimum number of idle threads. However, unnecessarily increasing these values can cause performance problems. If too many tasks start at the same time, all of them might appear to be slow. In most cases the thread pool will perform better with its own algorithm for allocating threads.

Comment: If I replace `Debug.WriteLine`call by `ConcurrentBag<string>.Add` and display the bag, I retrieve the expected behavior. You are right, it isn't scheduling problem, but resource allocation problem.